# If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, prove that for ∀ ε>0 ∃ interval [a,b]⊆R of length ε such that x_n∈[a,b] for infinitely many values of n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, prove that for any $ε>0$ there is an interval $[a,b]⊆R$ of length $ε$ such that $x_n∈[a,b]$ for infinitely many values of n.

Answer (score 0):

Every bounded sequence in the real numbers has at least one limit point (Bolzano-Weierstrauß theorem). If you take the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$-neighbourhood around that point, it will contain infinitely many $x_n$.